# Ajax filtration on the site loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, filtering

everybody!

I have a problem with `AJAX` filtration. In themplate of my wordpress site I have an AJAX filter, in which , you need , first of all pick a category ,and after you can do advanced filtration. Now I have only one category,

[image]

So I need to load my site already filtred by this request

```
?ajax_filter=true&sort-by=recent&property_type=for-sale
```

How can I do it with ajax or js? Thank you!

Comment: are you just asking, how to make an ajax request in javascript?

Comment: is this wordpress?

Comment: You could refer a tutorial something like this, https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-post-filters.html